# match one of several strings

Tags: regex, perl

I have a perl script that it opens many files and search for particular string what I need is to match if any string matched then go to the next file, here part of the script

I want to match one of the following:

```
function xyz () {
```

or

```
function xyz ()
{
```

or

```
xyz () {
```

or

```
{
```

or 
function abc_xyz_abc () {
or 
function abc_xyz_abc () 
{
or 
function ab_cd_ef () {
or 
abc_xyz () {
or 
abc_xyz () 
{

Here is some of my code:

```
if (( $match =~ m/function/)|| ($match =~ /()/)  || ($match =~ m/\W+\/())  .......{
   print "Matched: File $line\n";
   next;
} else {
   print "Not found\n";
}
```

Comment: You can use brackets for matching one of several alternatives. You also need to escape the brackets in your regular expressions if you're trying to match them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a single regular expression for this

`^(function)? ?\w+? ?(\(\))?\n? ? ?\{`

will match all the four of

```
function xyz () {

function xyz ()
{

xyz () {

{
```

also make sure you add a multiline `m` modifier

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mY1eD3/1)

Comment: thanks, but should xyx be something like this (\W+)? ?(()) as it might be different letters so I change it to: if ($match=~ m/(function)? ?(\w+)? ?(())?\n? ? ?\{/) {....also what if I want to exit the loop when mact is found and go the the next file, I used this line "return $1 if defined $1;" and it doesn't exit the loop thanks again..

Comment: yeah..you are correct...i was thinking only of your example....corrected the answer thred

Comment: thanks I thought I have it right using your recommendation but it just returns a few files not all the files, this is due to some of the file has "_" on the name such function xyz_abc or abc_xyz_abc_xyz, how can catch those?

Comment: not sure why it doesn't work for me, i tried the abc_x_abc() on demo and there was no match

Comment: see the full [demo](http://regex101.com/r/mY1eD3/1) If that doesnt work try replacing `\w` with `[a-z_]`

Comment: thanks I think the problem is it is matching string only if ends with "{" else it won't match say abc_abc ()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62891/discussion-between-user2912312-and-nu11p01n73r).

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly what permutations that you want to find you can store them in an array, then use the ~~ operator to check.

```
 #fill this with all permutations
 my @match_list = ('function abc() {','other example'); 
 if($test ~~ @match_list) {
      print "match!";
}
```